# Tracking user CPU hours

Tags: users, monitoring, multiuser

I am looking to work out which users on our system are using the most CPU resources.
to check this?

So I would like to find out:

- CPU-hours this month, (and % of total)
- CPU hours this week, (and % of total)
- CPU hours ever, (and % of total)

For both real users and system processes

Comment: Take a look at these Q&A's. (1) [Is the sum of all PIDs “utime” the total system utime?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32598/is-the-sum-of-all-pids-utime-the-total-system-utime/32619#32619) & (2) [What's the fairest way to monitor total CPU time - per user?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107456/whats-the-fairest-way-to-monitor-total-cpu-time-per-user). You're looking for the acct package. It provides a service, psacct, which collects this data and then reports it with the `sa -m` command. http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/Process-Accounting.html